# How to express "$n$ is a power of prime" as a logical formula without using exponential notation?

Tags: prime-numbers, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is a problem, which I encountered while self-studying discrete mathematics from MIT:

Express each of the following predicates and propositions in formal logic notation. The domain of discourse is the nonnegative integers, $\Bbb N$.

Moreover, in addition to the propositional operators, variables and quantifiers, you may define predicates using addition, multiplication, and equality symbols, and nonnegative integer con- stants ($0, 1, ...$), **but no exponentiation (like $x^y$)**.

For example, the predicate “$n$ is an even number” could be defined by either of the following formulas:

$\exists m.(2m= n )$ or alternatively $\exists m.(m+m = n )$

(a) $m$ is a divisor of $n$.

(b) $n$ is a prime number.

(c) $n$ is a power of a prime.

---

Now,

I've got (a) and (b) already, but need some help with (c).

(a) $\exists m\exists p. (mp=n)$

(b) $ ISPrime(n) ::= $(n > 1)$ ∧ \neg (\exists x \exists y. (x \gt 1 \land y \gt 1 \land (x.y=n) )) $

(c) ?

It may have been easier to express that $n$ is a product of two distinct primes. But, here I am struggling to express a recursive relation which is "$n$ is a power of a prime".

$n$ can only be obtained by multiplying $p$ with itself $k$ times (where $k$ in a non negative integer), but this has to be expressed without using exponential notation (a constraint imposed in the question). I could potentially reuse $ISPrime(p)$ from (b), but how?

Update:

Solution to (b) was corrected to account for a comment.

Comment: Your answer to (b) allows 1 to be  prime. That's not the usual definition.

Comment: thanks, corrected to add another condition

Comment: Using the implication operator should make life simpler, for example $$IsPrime(n) ::= (n > 1) \land ((x \cdot y = n) \implies x \in \{-n, -1, 1, n \})$$

Comment: Why not just 'if a divideds n and b divides n then a divides b or b divides a'? No need to use IsPrime.

Comment: The outer existential in your answer to (a) looks wrong to me, it introduces a second $m$ variable that makes the $mp$ ambiguous about which $m$ it refers to (making it either redundant or wrong respectively).

Comment: @Eric right, as what is being asked is to state "m is a divisor of n", I probably should not have introduced $m$ as a new variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have IsPrime then you can say that n is a multiple of at most one prime.

Comment: Yes. "multiple" is better than "product".  In either case IO think you're assuming the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: that's ingenious. So something like (p) ∧ ¬(∃q.((q) ∧ (q=)) ?

Comment: @senseiwu Not exactly. First, you should add quantifiers for your $p$ and $n$. Second, you want to write something like: "there do not exist two primes $p,q$ such that $n$ is a multiple of $pq$". (Equivalently: such that $n$ is a multiple of $p$ and a multiple of $q$.)

Comment: @Snaw I am usually good using _at-least_, but not so much with _at-most_. So, my next try is $((n=pq) \implies ISPRIME(p) \land ISPRIME(q) \land (p=q))$. What do you think?

Comment: @senseiwu There is still a problem, for instance $27=3^3$ but $27=27\cdot 1$ where neither of $27,1$ are primes. Or worse, $81=3^4$ but $81=9\cdot 9$ where $9$ isn't prime. Try translating the sentence I offered in my previous comment into mathematical notation.

Comment: true, I overlooked that aspect. Now I finally have $\neg (\exists p \exists q . (ISPRIME(p) \land ISPRIME(q) \land n = pq)) $. The reason for my intellectual discomfort -- though I fully understand the solution from fundamental theorem of arithmetic perspective -- is that nowhere it states that $n=p.p.p...$. We more or less just state that there are no two primes that can be combined to produce $n$

Comment: @senseiwu Still not quite done. You have to assert $p \ne q$. Note that you are still allowing $1$ to be a power of a prime, but that's probably OK since it's the $0$th power of any prime. The fact that $n$ is then a power of $p$ depends on the fact that every number is a product of primes. (You don't need the uniqueness part of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for pointing out the incompleteness. Given that  you are a Professor, I am taking the liberty to ask here another question (though I agree that this is not the forum for any such detailed discussion). 

It has been my experience while doing exercises from this textbook where I found the question (lehman, meyer), that questions are subdivided to 3 or 4 parts of increasing difficulty. 

Is this how some American universities manage to distinguish student's capabilities and categorize their grades accordingly (A students may solve (c)/s and (d)s)? Just curious and Thanks!!

Comment: @senseiwu That exercise structure in a textbook is meant to provide clues about how difficult a (part of a) problem might be. That can help a student learn. I've never thought of it as an explicit part of a grade. If I put such a question on an examination then students who did more parts would get better grades.

Comment: How about something like $\text{ISprime(p)} \land n=rp \Rightarrow \lnot (\exists q \ne p.(\text{ISprime(q)}\land n=sq))$

Answer (score 6):

Try expressing a unique feature of prime-powers.  Here's my take:

Prime-Power(x) == 'There is a P such that: (a) P is prime; (b) If y divides x, then either y=1 or P divides y'.  *[formalize in your favorite notation]*

(reason it out)

Comment: That’d be part b and is already solved. I had issues with part c where prime powers are involved

Comment: @senseiwu This isn't (b). It's satisfied by $9=3^2$. This answer might be marginally better than mine since it avoids having to know the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: @EthanBolker Got it, I got it mixed up then. I still keep your answer as green as it was easier to follow

Comment: @PMar this is also a great answer, now that I get your logic. Also, neatly builds on top of the solutions to previous problems (a) and (b)